# HostGator Showing error, while sending Mails

Tags: php

When we forwarding the emails from Host gator mail to gmail, it is automatically sending spam mails from Host gator to the forwarding gmail, mail box.

more than 10 will comes in a  day.

after this spam mail occur 
then we cannot sent mail from the site to the mail-server from the Web-page , then it shows the following error

[image]

***using Host Gator  control panel

Comment: use any one of these for SMTP port:- `25`,`465`,`587`

Comment: in the host gator how can we use the ports

Comment: Can't you change it in your mail code?.check this for help :-https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/outlook-eudora-thunderbird-mac-ipad-phone-client-settings  (check second image SMTP setting)  Or talk to support here via live chat and send him the problem as text directly:- http://support.hostgator.com/